# Converting Hibernate SQL to QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, querydsl

I'm trying to remove hardcoded SQL statements out of my repositories and convert them to Query DSL.

The most were pretty easy to convert, but this one is too much for my level of knowledge.

`ObjectStatus` is of type enum and can be `ENABLED` or `DISABLED`.

---

**Original:**

```
@Query(
    "SELECT DISTINCT cat " +
    "FROM PriceInfo pi " +
    "LEFT JOIN pi.article.categories cat " +
    "WHERE " +
        "cat.parent.id = :parentId " +
        "AND " +
        "pi.article.objectStatus = :articleObjectStatus " +
        "AND " +
        "cat.objectStatus = :categoryObjectStatus"
)
List<Category> findCategories(
    @Param("parentId")             Integer      parentId,
    @Param("articleObjectStatus")  ObjectStatus articleObjectStatus,
    @Param("categoryObjectStatus") ObjectStatus categoryObjectStatus
);
```

---

Trying to convert it to Query DSL, but don't know how.

Below is my latest attempt, but also I tried with many kind of joins - not working too.

---

**Not working:**

```
public List<Category> findCategories(
    final Integer      parentId,
    final ObjectStatus articleObjectStatus,
    final ObjectStatus categoryObjectStatus
) {
    final QPriceInfo pi  = QPriceInfo.priceInfo;
    final QCategory  cat = pi.article.categories.any();
    final JPAQuery<Category> q =
        new JPAQueryFactory(this.entityManager)
            .select(cat)
            .distinct()
            .from(pi)
            .leftJoin(pi.article.categories)
            .where(
                cat.parent.id.eq(parentId)
                .and(pi.article.objectStatus.eq(articleObjectStatus))
                .and(cat.objectStatus.eq(categoryObjectStatus))
            );
    // System.out.println(q);
    return q.fetch();
}
```